# Todolist not adding task

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When adding a task, no task adds. What is wrong? All other functions is working.
Also why is not the dialog window close automatically when entering a task?

The todolist is working good, otherwise. I have tried now for a weak to find a error in the code by changing and adding different type of codes, however I have not even come any close to a solution.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<title>To Do List Application</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
#container
{
width:700px;
height:450px;
margin:70px auto;
border:2px solid rgb(125, 181, 66);
}
h2{
color:rgb(125, 181, 66);
text-align: center;
}
#projects
{
width: 650px;
height:250px;
margin:0px auto;
}
ol li{
border:1px dotted black;
cursor:pointer;
padding:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
ol li:hover{
background: #6eb7d6;
}
#btnAddProject
{
margin-left: 540px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#btnAddTask
{
margin-left: 550px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.ui-icon-close
{
transform: scale(1.5);
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");
$("#projects").tabs();
$("ul").sortable({axis:"x", containment:"#projects"});
$("ol").sortable({axis:"y", containment:"#projects"});
$("#projects").on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function(){
$(this).closest("li").slideUp(function(){
$(this).remove();
});
});
$("#projects").on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function(){
var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
var id = $("#main li:eq(" + index + ") a").attr("href");
$("#main li:eq(" + index + ")").remove();
$(id).remove();
$("#projects").tabs("refresh");
});
$("#btnAddTask").button()
.click(function(){
$("#task-dialog").dialog({width:400, resizable:false, modal:true,
buttons:{
"Add new task": function(){
$("#projects").tabs("refresh");
var activeTab = $("#projects").tabs("option", "active");
var title = $("#main > li:nth-child(" + (activeTab+1) +") > a").attr("href");
$("#projects " + title).append("<li><input type='checkbox'>" + $("#new-task").val() + "</li>");
$("#new-task").val("");
$(this).dialog("close");
},
"Cancel":function(){
$("#new-task").val("");
$(this).dialog("close");
}
}
});
});
$("#btnAddProject").button()
.click(function(){ 
$("#project-dialog").dialog({width:400, resizable:false, modal:true,
buttons:{
"Add project":function(){
var projectName = $("#new-project").val();
var replaceName = projectName.split(" ").join("_");
$("<li><a href='#" + replaceName + "'>" + projectName + "</a></a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'></span></li>")
.appendTo("#main");
$("#projects").tabs("refresh");
$("<ol id='" + replaceName + "'></ol>").appentTo("#projects").sortable();
$("#projects").tabs("refresh");
var tabCount = $("#projects .ui-tabs-nav li").lenght;
$("#projects").tabs("option", "active", tabCount-1);
$("#new-project").val("");
$(this).dialog("close");
},
"Cancel":function(){
$("#new-project").val("");
$(this).dialog("close");
}
}});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h2>To Do List</h2>
<button id="btnAddProject">Add Project</button>
<div id="projects">
<ul id="main">
<li><a href="#personal">Personal</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></li>
<li><a href="#work">Work</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></li>
</ul>
<ol id="personal">
<li><input type="checkbox">Doctor appointment</li>
<li><input type="checkbox">Call the plumber</li>
</ol>
<ol id="work">
<li><input type="checkbox">Complete test case document</li>
<li><input type="checkbox">Meet project manager</li>
<li><input type="checkbox">Record jquery video</li>
</ol>
</div>
<button id="btnAddTask">Add Task</button>
<div id="project-dialog" title="Add a project" style="display:none;">
<label for="new-project">Project name:</label><input id="new-project" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="task-dialog" title="Add a task" style="display:none;">
<label for="new-task">Task name:</label><input id="new-task" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo. It's `appendTo`, not `appentTo`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


  <title>To Do List Application</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 700px;
      height: 450px;
      margin: 70px auto;
      border: 2px solid rgb(125, 181, 66);
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: rgb(125, 181, 66);
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #projects {
      width: 650px;
      height: 250px;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    
    ol li {
      border: 1px dotted black;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    ol li:hover {
      background: #6eb7d6;
    }
    
    #btnAddProject {
      margin-left: 540px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    #btnAddTask {
      margin-left: 550px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .ui-icon-close {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");
      $("#projects").tabs();
      $("ul").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        containment: "#projects"
      });
      $("ol").sortable({
        axis: "y",
        containment: "#projects"
      });
      $("#projects").on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
        $(this).closest("li").slideUp(function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      });
      $("#projects").on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function() {
        var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
        var id = $("#main li:eq(" + index + ") a").attr("href");
        $("#main li:eq(" + index + ")").remove();
        $(id).remove();
        $("#projects").tabs("refresh");
      });
      $("#btnAddTask").button()
        .click(function() {
          $("#task-dialog").dialog({
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
              "Add new task": function() {
                $("#projects").tabs("refresh");
                var activeTab = $("#projects").tabs("option", "active");
                var title = $("#main > li:nth-child(" + (activeTab + 1) + ") > a").attr("href");
                $("#projects " + title).append("<li><input type='checkbox'>" + $("#new-task").val() + "</li>");
                $("#new-task").val("");
                $(this).dialog("close");
              },
              "Cancel": function() {
                $("#new-task").val("");
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
            }
          });
        });
      $("#btnAddProject").button()
        .click(function() {
          $("#project-dialog").dialog({
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
              "Add project": function() {
                var projectName = $("#new-project").val();
                var replaceName = projectName.split(" ").join("_");
                $("<li><a href='#" + replaceName + "'>" + projectName + "</a></a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'></span></li>")
                  .appendTo("#main");
                $("#projects").tabs("refresh");
                $("<ol id='" + replaceName + "'></ol>").appendTo("#projects").sortable();
                $("#projects").tabs("refresh");
                var tabCount = $("#projects .ui-tabs-nav li").lenght;
                $("#projects").tabs("option", "active", tabCount - 1);
                $("#new-project").val("");
                $(this).dialog("close");
              },
              "Cancel": function() {
                $("#new-project").val("");
                $(this).dialog("close");
              }
            }
          });
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h2>To Do List</h2>
    <button id="btnAddProject">Add Project</button>
    <div id="projects">
      <ul id="main">
        <li><a href="#personal">Personal</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></li>
      </ul>
      <ol id="personal">
        <li><input type="checkbox">Doctor appointment</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Call the plumber</li>
      </ol>
      <ol id="work">
        <li><input type="checkbox">Complete test case document</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Meet project manager</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Record jquery video</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <button id="btnAddTask">Add Task</button>
    <div id="project-dialog" title="Add a project" style="display:none;">
      <label for="new-project">Project name:</label><input id="new-project" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="task-dialog" title="Add a task" style="display:none;">
      <label for="new-task">Task name:</label><input id="new-task" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```